# 'ProjectModuleName-Swift.h' file not found for iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I use both of Objctive-C and swift within a swift Framework.
I import the Xcode-generated header for my Swift code into any Objective-C .m file like `<ProjectModuleName/ProjectModuleName-Swift.h>` as [Apple suggest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c).
It works for the framework project.

While when I want to add the framework project to an app target project with the `pod ,:path` script in the Podfile , it meets the error `<ProjectModuleName/ProjectModuleName-Swift.h> file not found`  as follows.

```
/// Add the target framework from the Podfile
 pod "ProjectModuleName",:path => '../ProjectModuleName_Path/'
```

If I change the `<ProjectModuleName/ProjectModuleName-Swift.h>` in the framework to `ProjectModuleName-Swift.h`. It will be fine for the app project ,but it does't work for the framework project.

```
/// It will be fine for the app project ,but it does't work for the framework project.
#import  "ProjectModuleName-Swift.h"

/// It will be bad for the app project ,but it works for the framework project.
#import  <ProjectModuleName/ProjectModuleName-Swift.h>
```